# How to tranlate a square on the z axis using three.js?

Tags: javascript, html, transform, three.js, webgl

I need some help trying to translate a square on the z axis. Are there any examples on how best to do accomplish this using three.js?

Comment: what do you mean by 'transform' ? are you trying to resize the cube? or are you trying to move it (translate it)

Comment: yes move it (translate it) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
square.translateZ(50);
```

Object3D docs here: http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/docs/55/#Reference/Core/Object3D

Source here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/core/Object3D.js